# Running ArcPy function CADToGeodatabase() crashes ArcMap/ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, convert, microstation, dgn

My code:

```
    import arcpy, csv
    from arcpy import env

    dgnfile = str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0))
    outFeatureClass = str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1))  #the fc in my fgdb template to be  populated by data read from the dgn
    i = 0
    while outFeatureClass[i:i+4] <> ".gdb": i+=1
      inFeatureClass = outFeatureClass[:i+4]
      CADdataset = "GD_Temp"
      refscale = "1000"
      arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(dgnfile,inFeatureClass,CADdataset,refscale)
```

---

This is my code which crashes out.
I am able to read geometry out of a CAD dataset which has been created in ArcCatalog manually, and populate an existing FC in my FGDB. But the dgn-to-CADdataset part crashed. When I placed my first question I ASSUMED the CADToGeodatabase routine would work. Is it a simple Python code error? ESRI are their usual helpful self.
By the way, I've omitted the code which subsequently reads the output from CADToGeodatabase().

---

Following is what I am feeding into CADToGeodatabase routine, as quoted from PythonWin debug session (...=intevening folders):

argument 1:  'C:\GeneralWorkData\...\9202.dgn'
argument 2:  'C:\GeneralWorkData\...\GD_9202_ED5031N_FGDB_Pop.gdb'
argument 3:  'GD_Temp'
argument 4:  '1000'

It is supposed to create a new feature dataset in the .gdb, which is what I am trying to achieve here.

The Sample Code you mentioned is the method I am using for my work, but it crashes ArcMap/ArcCatalog/PythonWin Debug, with no (helpful) error message. These are the right argument formats according to Resource Centre Help for ArcGIS 10.0!

Don't want to look at "Interoperability"(?) right now, as I have code which works to read out of the CADToGeodatabase results so it would mean starting all over again. In other words, I can import dgn data by hand in Catalog then read that data in Python and put it where I like, so the second half of the Python project is done, now I need the first. I posted originally prematurely, didn't know this would crash, apologies again. Is there any chance someone could try this routine with real dgn data, cos I am thinking we are looking at an ESRI bug...?

Answer (score 1):

Check the syntax you are supplying to CADtoGeodatabase because it expects:

```
CADtoGeodatabase_conversion (input_cad_datasets, out_gdb_path, out_dataset_name, reference_scale, {spatial_reference})
```

You seem to be giving it a Feature Class name where it expects a path to a Geodatabase.

There is a Code Sample you could follow in the [CAD to Geodatabase (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000001z000000) documentation.

However, it may be that this tool which creates a Feature Dataset is not what you need because I think you are trying to populate an existing (and empty) Feature Class.

Perhaps try re-phrasing your question along the lines of "How to populate existing (and empty) Feature Class from Microstation *.dgn?".  I don't know the answer to that (but would try Data Interoperabilty, if I had it) - but someone else might.